# extracting a value from json file into html doc

Tags: html, json

How do I extract the odds value from this
JSON File and append it to a html-document?

```
  [{"id":"128995",
    "home":"RB Leipzig",
    "away":"FC Heidenheim",
    "homeLogo":"36360.png","awayLogo":"5885.png",
    "url":"",
    "odds1":"1.47","
    oddsx":"4.39",
    "odds2":"8.40"}]
```

HTML:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    /*script src*/
    </head>
    <body>
    <span id="odds"></span> /*output value from json odds */
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON( "http://myJson.json", function( data ) {
           var items = [];
           items.push( "<span>"+ data.odds1 + data.odds2 + "</span><br />" );
        });
    });
 </script>
```

I want to extract `odds1` `oddsx` `odds2` and put those values into a HTML file.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What programming language? It doesn't appear that you have tried anything other than "reading up on it"...

Comment: i've included a json file :)

Comment: json is programming language agnostic

Comment: updated post for clarification.

Comment: HTML is also programming language agnostic … unless `/*script src*/` is an attempt at trying to imply that you want to use client side JavaScript. Tutorials for that are ten a penny. Learn the basics, show us what you've tried.

Comment: Do an AJAX request, run the response through a JSON parser, access the keys from the hash object (for example `json["odds1"]`) to stick them into the HTML element.

Comment: use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)  $.getJSON('mydata.json', function(data) {
    //your code
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if you are willing to use something like jQuery.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON TEST</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.5" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $.getJSON( "http://pathto/test.json", function( data ) {
          var items = [];
          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<span id='" + key + "'>" + key + ":  " + val + "</span><br />" );
          });

          $( "<div/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: "<p>Summary of JSON data:</p>" + items.join( "" )
          }).appendTo( "body" );
          $("#odds").html("odds1:  " + data.odds1 + ", oddsx:  " + data.oddsx + ", odds2:  " + data.odds2);
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="odds"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file

```
{"id":"128995","home":"RB Leipzig","away":"FC Heidenheim","homeLogo":"36360.png","awayLogo":"5885.png","url":"","odds1":"1.47","oddsx":"4.39","odds2":"8.40"}
```

Comment: The output would look like:

odds1: 1.47, oddsx: 4.39, odds2: 8.40
Summary of JSON data:

    id: 128995
    home: RB Leipzig
    away: FC Heidenheim
    homeLogo: 36360.png
    awayLogo: 5885.png
    url: 
    odds1: 1.47
    oddsx: 4.39
    odds2: 8.40

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
 <script id="myJson" type="application/json">
 { 
    "id":"128995",
    "home":"RB Leipzig",
    "away":"FC Heidenheim",
    "homeLogo":"36360.png","awayLogo":"5885.png",
    "url":"",
    "odds1":"1.47",
    "oddsx":"4.39",
    "odds2":"8.40"
 }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var x = JSON.parse($('#myJson').html());
        console.log(x.odds1);
        console.log(x.odds2);
        console.log(x.oddsx);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: The question is asking how to parse JSON from a file, not embedded in the current document. That code will error as `$` is undefined. The question is asking how to put the values in HTML, that code won't do that, it just tries to log them to the console.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question